# SphinxQL - How to match words within a single string

Tags: sphinx, match, sphinxql

I have the following and several other strings indexed. All words are glued together.

> Stringisaflexiblepieceofropeortwinewhichisusedtotie,bind,orhangotherobjects.

Which is a sentence from wikipedia.

> String is a flexible piece of rope or twine which is used to tie, bind, or hang other objects.

I use SphinxQL to search for several words. E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE MATCH('piece rope bind');
```

This should return the above string as a result, but it returns 0 rows.

How should the query look like to not look for words, but to simply match the words in a string?

I have played already with the ranker options like

```
SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE MATCH('piece rope bind') OPTION ranker=matchany';
```

but with no success.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min_infix_len` - to enable infix searching http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len

You probably want `enable_star = 0`

Or maybe you could use WordBreaker to rebreak the long string before indexing :)
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/01/29/a-new-tool-in-the-trunk-wordbreaker/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The wordbreak tool is interesting, but is not available yet. I will try the min_infix_len option now. Setting enable_star = 0 will disable the * option, but how should this help?

Comment: Wordbreaker is available, I've used it myself. You just grab it from svn https://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/checkout

Comment: Thanks! One thing though. Why do I want 'enable_star = 0'?

Comment: if you set enable_star =1 then you will need to add stars into the query to match part words.